# Is there any way to change the style of select options in vue?

Tags: css, forms, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

[image]

I was wondering if we can anyhow change the color or fonts of the select options. I am taking the example from this link https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-select#form-select Tried to do some modifications with css but does not seem like working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those kind of inputs are not customizable as of today.
Some standards are discussed, especially Open UI: https://open-ui.org/components/select

But there is no way to customize those elements, they are baked in into our devices and set by constructors (Apple, Android, Safari, Chrome etc...).

The only way is to replicate the same behavior but with a totally different visual. This is at least the only solution as of today and what most of CSS frameworks are doing (but not bootstrap-vue as you can see).

Comment: Yes, bootsrapvue uses directly the native select unlike Vuetify which have more customizable components